# VBO glDrawElements and glVertexAttribPointer on GLES2.0 displays nothing

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I can display a texture using shaders, glVertexAttribPointer and glDrawArrays like so:

Init

```
const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.33f,
    0.5f, -0.33f,
    -0.5f,  0.33f,
    0.5f,  0.33f
};


const GLfloat squareTex[] = {
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1
};


glEnableVertexAttribArray(PositionTag);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TexCoord0Tag);

glVertexAttribPointer(PositionTag, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, squareVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(TexCoord0Tag, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, squareTex);
```

And for draw

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

But I'm having difficulty converting to VBOs, shaders and glDrawElements.  This is the code I have so far, but nothing displays:

Header

```
typedef struct MyVertex
{
    float x, y, z;        //Vertex
    float nx, ny, nz;     //Normal
    float s0, t0;         //Texcoord0
} MyVertex;

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))
```

Init

```
glGenBuffers(1, &VertexVBOID);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);

MyVertex pvertices[4];
//Fill the pvertices array
pvertices[0].x = -0.5f;
pvertices[0].y = -0.33f;
pvertices[0].z = 0.0;
pvertices[0].nx = 0.0;
pvertices[0].ny = 0.0;
pvertices[0].nz = 1.0;
pvertices[0].s0 = 0.0;
pvertices[0].t0 = 0.0;

pvertices[1].x = 0.5f;
pvertices[1].y = -0.33f;
pvertices[1].z = 0.0;
pvertices[1].nx = 0.0;
pvertices[1].ny = 0.0;
pvertices[1].nz = 1.0;
pvertices[1].s0 = 1.0;
pvertices[1].t0 = 0.0;

pvertices[2].x = -0.5f;
pvertices[2].y = 0.33f;
pvertices[2].z = 0.0;
pvertices[2].nx = 0.0;
pvertices[2].ny = 0.0;
pvertices[2].nz = 1.0;
pvertices[2].s0 = 0.0;
pvertices[2].t0 = 1.0;

pvertices[3].x = 0.5f;
pvertices[3].y = 0.33f;
pvertices[3].z = 0.0;
pvertices[3].nx = 0.0;
pvertices[3].ny = 0.0;
pvertices[3].nz = 1.0;
pvertices[3].s0 = 1.0;
pvertices[3].t0 = 1.0;

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(MyVertex)*4, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(MyVertex)*4, pvertices);


glGenBuffers(1, &IndexVBOID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);

int pindices[6];
pindices[0]=0;
pindices[1]=1;
pindices[2]=2;
pindices[3]=2;
pindices[4]=1;
pindices[5]=3;
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int)*6, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(int)*6, pindices);
```

Draw

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(PositionTag);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(NormalTag);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TexCoord0Tag);

glVertexAttribPointer(PositionTag, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glVertexAttribPointer(NormalTag, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
glVertexAttribPointer(TexCoord0Tag, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(24));

//    glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLES, x, y, z, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_INT, 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml), `GL_INT` is not a valid type to use for indices in `glDrawElements`. Try using `unsigned int`s for your indices (and of course `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` in `glDrawElements`). You may still use your `int` data as indices, but as `glDrawElements` needs `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, it would be more consistent to make the array `unsigned int`.

**EDIT:** After looking into the specification (based on your tags I took the ES 2.0 spec), they seem to further limit it to unsigned byte and unsigned short. I don't know if it is that limited in iOS, but we can conclude that the data has at least to be unsigned. On the other hand I haven't found any statement about a possible `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error that is thrown on a wrong type argument, but it would be reasonable to get one.

Comment: which brings up the following point: Zeophlite should test if GL reports errors in debug. glDrawElements should report GL_INVALID_ENUM then.

Comment: @Bahbar Although it should obviously, a wrong type argument is not listed on the given reference link as a source for GL_INVALID_ENUM. That's why I haven't stated it explicitly in my answer. But the link still says that only the unsigneds are valid. Maybe I should check the spec for clarification.

Comment: Yup, the spec on errors applies to all enums, not specifically to each command. "If a command that requires an enumerated value is passed a symbolic constant that is not one of those speciﬁed as allowable for that command, the error INVALID_ENUM error is generated."

Comment: Thanks for the answer Christian, I actually figured it out beforehand, but StackOverflow didn't allow me to post an answer.  Also @Bahbar, there was no error generated! (I removed my error checking code for my post)

Comment: @Zeophlite: then it's a driver bug. File it :D ?

Comment: @Bahbar It needn't be a driver bug, maybe just a spec inaccuracy. As I said, they list every error that can be generated by wrong arguments to `glDrawElements`, except the errors for a wrong type argument, maybe there is none.

Comment: The quote I gave is from the spec and is unambiguous. And it encompasses all GLES commands. So... if it does not flag the error, it _is_ a driver bug. And it definitely is a man page "bug".

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't look terribly wrong, so this time the devil is somewhere in the details. My guess is, that your use of a struct and its data fields' alignments don't match the offsets passed to OpenGL.

I suggest you use the [`offsetof()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) macro found in *stddef.h* to portably get the offsets of the data fields.